# Segregate value from single textbox

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

Need a small help.

The below script picks the value from the textbox and add it to the URL and opens it.

Example:

Text Box value:

```
one
two
three
Four
Five
Six
Seven
```

Output URL:
https://www.google.com/search?q=one+two+three+four+five+six+seven

The help I need:

I want the textbox value to be again split into two variables based on the separator for example a comma (the script is already splitting the text box value based on new line) and store the value in two different variables.

Example:

Text Box value:

```
one,two
three,four
five,six
```

This value should be split based on ','

Example:

```
val1= one;
val2= two;
```

Output URL:
https://www.google.com/search?q=val1+val2

This should be in a loop so that once the first set of values are executed, it moves to the next one:

Example:

```
val1= three;
val2= four;
```

Output URL:
https://www.google.com/search?q=val1+val2

```js
$(function() {
  $("#text1").click(function() {
    if ($('#textbox1').val() != '') {
      var search_container1 = $("#textbox1").val().split(" ");
      for (k = 0; k < search_container1.length; k++) {
        search_container1[k] = search_container1[k].replace(/\s/gi, "+");
      }
      var srcbox1 = "val1234";

      if (srcbox1 == "val1234") {
        var search_val1234 = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < search_container1.length; i++) {
          search_val1234 = search_container1[i]; {
            window.open("https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=" + search_val1234 + "");
          }
        }

      }
    } else if ($('#textbox1').val() == '') {
      alert("Enter Keyword");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="col-sm">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <center><a>Deal IDs</a></center>
        <br>
        <textarea id="textbox1" cols="5" rows="7"></textarea><br>
        <center><br><button id="text1" class="btn btn-warning btn-block ">Submit</button></center>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can form an array of array first. Since you are sending it thru an URL, you need to do encodeURIComponent.

```
function getValues(val, delimiter) {
  var results = [];
  val.split("\n").forEach(function(line) {
    results.push(line.split(delimiter).map(function(token, i) {
      return encodeURIComponent(token);
    }));
  });
  return results
}

var arrayOfArray = getValues("one,two\nthree,four\nfive,six", ',');
arrayOfArray.forEach(function(arr) {
  console.log("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + arr.join("+"));
});
```

Comment: I want the values separated as val1 and val2 as i need to use it as different parts of the URL. Dummy Example: https://www.google.'+val1+'/search?q='+val2+'